# Debug apt / Installing Docker - Unable to locate package docker-ce

Tags: debian, docker, apt

I have followed [official instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493460/how-to-install-add-apt-repository-using-the-terminal) for Docker installation - Debian Jessie.

- In `/etc/apt/sources.list` it says now,

  `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jessie stable`
- `apt-get update` seems to download packages correctly (output below)
- but then, on `apt-get install docker-ce`, the system reports to be "unable to locate package docker-ce".

**How can I debug what is happening?** Never had this before.

Output of `apt-get update`:

```
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en
Hit https://download.docker.com jessie InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://http.debian.net jessie InRelease
Hit https://download.docker.com jessie/stable amd64 Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie-updates InRelease
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie Release.gpg
Get:1 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en_US [587 B]
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie/all Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie-updates/main Sources
Get:2 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en [584 B]
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie-updates/contrib Sources
Get:3 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en_US [587 B]
Get:4 http://http.debian.net jessie-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex [8,884 B]
Get:5 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en [584 B]
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie-updates/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie-updates/contrib Translation-en
Get:6 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en_US [587 B]
Get:7 http://http.debian.net jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [3,688 B]
Get:8 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en [584 B]
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie Release
Get:9 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en_US [587 B]
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/main Sources
Get:10 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en [584 B]
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/contrib Sources
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/main i386 Packages
Get:11 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en_US [587 B]
Ign https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en_US
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net jessie/main Translation-en
Get:12 https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en [584 B]
Ign https://download.docker.com jessie/stable Translation-en
```

Answer (score 0):

To install `docker-ce` on debian jessie:

After adding `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jessie stable` to your `/etc/sources.list`. ( you don't need the `software-properties-common` package or the `add-apt-repository` command)

Install the required package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
```

Add the `gpg` key:

```
curl -fsSl https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-get key add -
```

Update and search for `docker-ce` package:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search docker-ce
```

Then  install the `docker-ce` package:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still unable to install docker-ce because it appears (?) it's only being built for amd64 and some arm configuration.  But I am on different hardware and/or running on a virtual server that for some reason reports its architecture as "i386".  Is there no way to make this work for the rest of us?  It really appears there is no way to use it if you're not on amd64 or whatever the other one is.. I've looked high and low, but so far every method has failed because binary distros are not avail for other platforms.  Am I mistaken? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Specific answer for linuxmint user.
Description:    Linux Mint 20.1
Codename:   ulyssa

While offical [release](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/) (ubuntu), have the necessary file and the [official docker installation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package) method using dpkg. You can download manually the necessary file and install it using dpkg

---

I try the official script to install but it fails.

---

#### Disclaimer, it may have unintended drawback

It avaliable on [snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/docker/mint), just do `sudo snap install docker`